# Excel: how to copy corresponding values from different column when values are outside of a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, `X` and `Y`. I usually look at the `Y` column and look for values outside the range of `-20` to `20`. I don't care about every value but rather the first and last in every group. For those values (first and last `Y` value outside of the range of `-20` to `20`), I want to copy the corresponding `X` value in another part of the sheet.

I have a Mac if this makes any difference. Please check the picture attached for clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In cell C2, put the formula: `=OR(B2<-20,B2>20)` and fill down.  In cell D2, put the formula `=AND(C2=C3,C2=C1)` and fill down.  Then filter for a TRUE value in column C and a FALSE value in column D.

I tested it briefly and it appears to work.  This would only get you the individual values though.  You would have to do more to get which group the values are from.